# Couldn't get ID from cakephp form in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, cakephp-2.x

I'd created a form in cakephp which has ID showing by default as `id="data[TemplateSection][0][TemplateDetail][0][Topic]"`. I want to get this element by ID in JavaScript and I wrote

```
Topic = document.getElementById("data[TemplateSection][0][TemplateDetail][0][Topic]").value;
```

But this is not working. How could I get this done?

Comment: Brackets aren't valid characters for an element ID. You'd instead need to treat `id` as an attribute rather than a true id: `document.querySelector('[id="data[TemplateSection][0][TemplateDetail][0][Topic]]"]')`

Comment: @Ouroborus thanks. i'd just corrected it.